# Pritunl client disconnected on M1 mac

Tags: apple-m1, pritunl

I've downloaded the latest arm package from Pritunl website: https://client.pritunl.com/#install . Then, I imported an ovpn profile that worked perfectly well on my older (intel) mac and on my coworkers laptop. But, the vpn keeps getting set to disconnected whenver I hit the connect button. In system logs, I see - `failed to sync config`. In server logs - `Unexpected profile exit`. I've tried downloading the client again and reimporting the profile but none of that's worked so far.
Current Pritunl client version - `1.2.3128`

Comment: Did you had a chance to fix the problem?

Comment: not yet @Abdulbosid. Pritunl has a new version available so maybe it includes the fix?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on my m1 Mac.  We solved it by restarting the pritunl service at the server side.  After doing so, problem disappeared.
Good luck.